# Print lines containing a given number followed by tab at least n times

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a tab delimited file:

```
scaffold_0      102     1       4       0       1       1       1       2       1       2       1       3
scaffold_0      103     1       4       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       1       3
scaffold_0      104     2       4       0       2       3       5       2       1       2       7       3
scaffold_0      105     1       4       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       1       3
scaffold_0      106     1       4       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       1       3
scaffold_0      107     2       3       3       2       5       1       2       1       2       2       4
scaffold_0      108     1       4       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       2       5
scaffold_0      109     1       4       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       2       5
scaffold_0      110     1       3       0       2       1       1       2       1       2       2       5
scaffold_0      111     1       3       0       2       1       1       1       1       2       2       5
```

and need to grab the lines for which numbers equal or bigger than 2 show up in 9 or more columns. 
So that I have:

```
scaffold_0      104     2       4       0       2       3       5       2       1       2       7       3
scaffold_0      107     2       3       3       2       5       1       2       1       2       2       4
```

Another way of putting is that I have to delete lines for which the counts of 0s and 1s bigger than 2 per line.

I have tried:

```
grep '[2-9]\t{9,}'
```

It doesn't work and even if it did it wouldnt grab 10, 11, 101, etc.

(grabbing 2, 12, 22, etc shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: All numbers are smaller then 10? Does the first number `104` count? Can the numbers be negative?

Comment: Numbers can be bigger than 104 and no negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) c+=($i>=2)} c>8' file
scaffold_0      104     2       4       0       2       3       5       2       1       2       7       3
scaffold_0      107     2       3       3       2       5       1       2       1       2       2       4
```

That will work in any shell on any UNIX box and will run orders of magnitude faster than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: It's indeed the fastest approach. Thanks!

Comment: Fastest, most concise, most portable - ie. the right way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    count=$(
        <<<"$line" cut -f2- | 
        tr '\t' '\n' | 
        grep -x '0\|1' | 
        wc -l
    )
    if (( count <= 2 )); then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done <file
```

For each line, get all the fields from the file starting from the second, then substitute tabs for newlines, filter only lines with zero or one, then count the number of lines. If the count is lower or equal to 2, print the line.

1. I went with zeros and ones cause I think it will be faster (less lines for wc -l to count, less lines for grep to print), but you can `grep -v -x '0\|1' | wc -l` and `(( count > 9 ))` as easily.
2. I have a feeling that someone will post a better awk solution, but I don't know awk that well to write such myself.
3. This will not work with negative numbers.

Live example at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/1NqvBJ).

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

```
while read x ; do 
    numgrep -l '/2../' <<< "$x" | { [ $(wc -l) -ge 9 ] && echo "$x" ; } ; 
done < file
```

Output:

```
scaffold_0      104     2       4       0       2       3       5       2       1       2       7       3
scaffold_0      107     2       3       3       2       5       1       2       1       2       2       4
```

---

Note: `numgrep`, and this code, will work correctly with both negative numbers and decimals.